# Cannot type '^' (caret) in native KDE apps

Tags: kde

I cannot type the caret character '^' in native KDE apps, such as plasmoids, editors (Kate, KWrite), etc.

It worked in previous (older) versions of KDE (3.5, I think). I believe it may be related to the fact that I'm using a keyboard with a german layout, however, it would seem farfetched - I can type the caret character just fine in non-KDE apps (such as chrome, firefox, etc).

I tried switching keyboard layouts, but no cigar. What's going on? What do I have to change to get the caret character back?

Comment: Did you try to press the key twice? Or once and then the space key? On my german keyboard with Gnome/Unit I have to do this to get the caret to display...

Comment: @oddfellow I have to press the key twice. as far as I know it has always been that way (even on windows!). I tried to do it with the space bar, but to no success :(

Answer (score 0):

Same happened for me, only way to get it back was to switch to a keyboard layout without deadkeys.

Comment: @Demizey Can you explain *how* to do this? (You can edit your answer to include this information.)